# Consultas com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento

Comecei recentemente com laravel e estou com uma dúvida terrível. Já fiz várias pesquisas no google que só me deixaram mais confusa ainda.
Tenho uma tabela de notícias e uma tabela de fotos. Cada notícia possue várias fotos. Na *home* tem que aparecer as duas últimas notícias e a respectiva foto de destaque.
No sql puro eu faço assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id_noticias DESC limit 2";
$res = $conexao->query($sql);
$dado= $res->fetch_assoc();

$sql_foto2= "select * from fotos where id_noticia =".$dado['id_noticias'];
```

Na tabela de fotos há o campo id_noticia ligado com a chave primária id_noticias da tabela `noticias`.

Como que eu faço isso em Laravel?

tabela fotos
id_fotos (auto_incremento e chave primaria)
endereco
id_noticia

tabela noticias
id_noticias (auto_incremento e chave primaria)
texto
titulo
pasta

```html
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#197 (1) 
{ ["items":protected]=> array(2) 
{ [0]=> object(App\Noticias)#200 (25) 
{ ["table":protected]=> string(12) "not_noticias" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(11) "id_noticias" ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["fillable":protected]=> array(7) 
{ [0]=> string(5) "texto" [1]=> string(6) "titulo" [2]=> string(7) "legenda" [3]=> string(5) "pasta" [4]=> string(9) "subtitulo" [5]=> string(6) 
"evento" [6]=> string(13) "titulo_evento" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true)
["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true)
["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(11) { ["id_noticias"]=> int(2246) ["texto"]=> string(689) 
"O curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra,...." ["titulo"]=> string(98) "Curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra Dracena desenvolve projeto Aproximação Prática Enfermagem (APE)" 
["legenda"]=> string(49) "Alunas do curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra Dracena" ["pasta"]=> string(4) "2242" ["subtitulo"]=> string(0) "" 
["evento"]=> string(0) "" ["titulo_evento"]=> string(0) "" ["data"]=> string(10) "2017-07-05" ["usuario"]=> string(8) "noticias" ["ativa"]=> string(1) "s" } 
["original":protected]=> array(11) { ["id_noticias"]=> int(2246) ["texto"]=> string(689) "O curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra,....
["titulo"]=> string(98) "Curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra Dracena desenvolve projeto Aproximação Prática Enfermagem (APE)" 
["legenda"]=> string(49) "Alunas do curso de Enfermagem da Unifadra Dracena" ["pasta"]=> string(4) "2242" ["subtitulo"]=> string(0) "" 
["evento"]=> string(0) "" ["titulo_evento"]=> string(0) "" ["data"]=> string(10) "2017-07-05" ["usuario"]=> string(8) "noticias" 
["ativa"]=> string(1) "s" } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) {
 } ["events":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(1)
 { ["fotos"]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#199 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) {
 } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } [1]=> object(App\Noticias)#201 
 (25) { ["table":protected]=> string(12) "not_noticias" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(11) "id_noticias" ["timestamps"]=> bool(false)
 ["fillable":protected]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "texto" [1]=> string(6) "titulo" [2]=> string(7) "legenda" [3]=> string(5) "pasta" [4]=> string(9) 
 "subtitulo" [5]=> string(6) "evento" [6]=> string(13) "titulo_evento" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3)
 "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) 
 ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(11) { ["id_noticias"]=> int(2245) ["texto"]=> string(2403)
```

Estou achando que o problema está na hora de eu retornar para view.
na view está assim:

```html
@foreach ($noticias as $key=> $not)
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="panel-heading">
              <img src={{asset('public/'.$not->endereco)}}>
              <h4>{{ $not->titulo }}</h4>
              <p align="justify">
                  <a href="#" class="noticia">
                     {{$texto = substr($not->texto,0,150)." ..."}}
                   </a>
              </p>
          </div>
    </div> 
@endforeach
```

No controller está assim:

```html
public function index()
     {

        $noticias = Noticias::with(['fotos' => function($query){
                    $query->take(1); 
                 }])
                ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
                ->take(2)
                ->get();
        //return view('inc.noticias')->with('query_noticias',$noticias);
        return view('inc.noticias',compact('noticias'));
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso da tabela de fotos, o campo nome não estou usando. O que preciso que seja retornado é o campo endereço. Este campo nome será retirado. As pastas existem no servidor com os mesmos nomes que estão armazenados na tabela de noticias.

A relação das tabelas está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

MODELS

```html
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Noticias;
class Fotos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'not_fotos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_foto';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
     'nome',
     'endereco',
     'id_noticia'
    ];
   public function noticia(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Noticias::class);
    }
}
?>

<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Noticias extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'not_noticias';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_noticias';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable =[
     'texto',
     'titulo',
     'legenda',
     'pasta',
     'subtitulo',
     'evento',
     'titulo_evento'
    ];
    public function fotos()
            {
                return $this->hasMany(Fotos::class,'id_noticia','id_noticias'); 
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: Você fez o `Model` dessas duas tabelas e colocou os relacionamentos?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic!
No model de noticias coloquei assim: 'public function fotos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Fotos::class);
    }'.

Comment: está certo a relação e algum problema seu ai? se já deu um `var_dump($noticias)` no retorno? se pode fazer isso e colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, já dei um var_dump sim, mas o resultado é muito grande pra eu postar aqui.

Comment: Cola só um registro?

Comment: nesse var_dump não retorna nenhuma foto e sua view também tem problemas eu to achando que é na sua tabelas que o problema tem! tem que fazer um pente fino para saber porque o código está correto, o problema são nas informações armazenadas, tem como mandar um print das duas tabelas com as os dados.?

Comment: Gisele o intrigante é que está tudo certo e a minha resposta cabe ai dentro, fica complicado dizer algo porque talvez seja uma bobeira, coloque as duas `Models` Noticias e Fotos na sua pergunta faltou isso para tirar a última conclusão.  ?Um outra coisa teste a solução 1 também para ver o que acontece sem o take!

Comment: Gisele cadê as configurações belongsTo que no meu tem o seu não ... Falta isso pra retornar os valores. O hasMany também tem olha lá no.meu exemplo. A view ta com problema tambem

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, desculpa mas não entendi... vc fala nos models, ou na tabela?? Confesso que estou perdidinha e pior, sendo pressionada pq preciso fazer isso aqui pra serviço meu...Se for no model, está lá sim, olha lá! E o que está errado na view???

Comment: Eu imagino que estais mesmo tem que colocar.os relacionamentos no outro tambem tudo no Model

Comment: Cheguei em um ponto que melhor eu desistir. Não sei mais o que eh pra fazer...

Answer (score 2):

Vou propor um exemplo minimo, na verdade se sua relação dita no comentário estiver correta (***acredito que pelas chaves informadas está fora do padrão e precisa então ser configurada***) é só fazer o seguinte:

***Exemplo minimo:***

Observe a configuração do relacionamento estipulando as chaves:

```
class Noticia extends Model 
{
    public function fotos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Fotos::class,'id_noticia','id_noticias'); 
    }
}
```

Pela sua `SQL` é só fazer assim:

```
$noticias = Noticia::with('fotos')
    ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
    ->take(2)
    ->get();
```

nesse caso trarás todas as noticias e todas as fotos correspondentes, mas, se quiser otimizar o número de fotos para 1 (***na tela acredito ser uma foto***) poderia fazer assim:

```
$noticias = Noticia::with(['fotos' => function($query)
    {
        $query->take(1);
    })
    ->orderBy('id_noticias','DESC')
    ->take(2)
    ->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)
- [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: Olá, @VirgilioNovic! Fiz da forma sugerida. As notícias retornaram, mas as  fotos não. No model de notícias coloquei em uma function fotos o que me sugeriu: 'return $this->hasMany(Fotos::class,'id_noticia','id_noticias'); '

Comment: @GiselePassoni passa as duas tabelas na sua pergunta! é pra funcionar sim, e outra coisa será que tem registro nas tabelas? mas, passe o layout das duas tabelas!

Comment: Excelente @VirgilioNovic!

Comment: não use sql puro na model, use o query builder (Eloquent) como o Virgilio mostrou